# ImportError: cannot import name 'transfer_markers' when testing with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

When I run tests for my python project by running the following command:

```
python setup.py test
(or)
pytest project_name
```

I get the following error:

```
.../project_name/.eggs/pytest_asyncio-0.9.0-py3.6.egg/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py", line 8, in <module>
from _pytest.python import transfer_markers

ImportError: cannot import name 'transfer_markers'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I looked it up online, there was almost no mention of that particular error message anywhere. Something similar has happened to me a few times before where previously working code just breaks and it's usually because there's a new version of an important package.

I looked at the [pytest release history](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/#history), and it looks like `pytest==4.1.0` has been released a few hours ago (as of this post).

The solution is to revert back to the last stable version of pytest i.e. `pytest==4.0.2` by running the following command:

```
pip install pytest==4.0.2
```

The tests are running now.

Comment: Related `pytest-asyncio` issue: [#104](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/104)

Comment: `pytest-asyncio` has now been updated to `0.10.0` which fixes this.

Comment: I get a TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert' after installed the mentioned version

Answer (score 6):

**pytest-asyncio has been updated to 0.10.0**

pytest-asyncio is using transfer_markers which is taken out in pytest 4.1.0.
Looks like it's fixed and released.
Issue[#105](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/pull/105)

EDIT: You can now upgrade `pip install pytest-asyncio==0.10.0` to fix this issue.

Or update `pytest-asyncio==0.10.0` in your requirements.txt

Don't forget to run `pip uninstall pytest` to keep your pytest up-to-date if you previously installed pytest 4.0.2 to temporarily fix the issue